How to store docx files to cloudinary with Multer
I am trying to upload docx file to cloudinary with multer-storage-cloudinary.
Here is the code I use
const storage = new CloudinaryStorage({
    cloudinary,
    params: async (req, file) => ({
        folder: 'client-documents',
        resource_type: 'raw',
        allowed_formats: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx'],
        public_id: `${Date.now()}`
    })
});

const upload = multer({
    storage,
    limits: { fileSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024 } // 10 MB limit
});

But when try with postman I get error
{
    "status": "error",
    "error": {
        "message": "An unknown file format not allowed",
        "name": "Error",
        "http_code": 400,
        "storageErrors": [],
        "statusCode": 500,
        "status": "error"
    },
    "message": "An unknown file format not allowed"
}

And see below my preset:
preset screenshot
What should I do?

1- The upload preset you're showing is not set as a default via API nor is it specified in your code, so unless it's set somewhere else, it shouldn't be a factor
2- Cloudinary always recommends using one of the official SDKs, since this is a third-party package they may not be regularly updating https://cloudinary.com/documentation/cloudinary_sdks
3- Without looking at the actual document it's hard to say where the issue lies. You should try uploading without filetype restriction to see what happens.
4- If you're still having issues, open a support ticket direct with Cloudinary
